# "gulp build" gives "process.on('exit'," Unexpected Identifier in gulpfile.js

Tags: node.js, gulp

When running `npm run build`, where build is defined as `build": "gulp build"` in package.json.

Gulp version being used is:

```
"gulp": "^3.9.1"
```

Node version is:

```
v0.10.32
```

The error on the command line is:

```
> gulp build


/Users/mhoggan/Development/dashboard/gulpfile.js:48
process.on('exit', function(code) {
^^^^^^^
SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
```

The code that generates the error is:

```
process.on('exit', function(code) {
  if (node) {
    node.kill();
  }
});
```

I thought process was a global object? Even the doc for 0.10.32 at [Node.js v0.10.32](https://nodejs.org/docs/v0.10.32/api/process.html) says it exists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unexpected identifier is a syntax error, meaning `process` may still be a global object but node hasn't even tried resolving it. The problem isn't with `process`, but the code before, as the javascript runtime wasn't expecting a new expression to start. You have probably missed a closing bracket somewhere before that line?

See [Syntax Error](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syntax_error) on wikipedia or more info on what a syntax error is.